# Could not locate ResponseBody converter error using LoganSquareConverterFactory

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2, logan-square

i am trying Retrofit2 with LoganSquare.when i try to handle custom error its showing error Could not locate ResponseBody converter for class.

My Error Utils class

```
public class ErrorUtils {
    public static APIError parseError(Response<?> response) {
        Converter<ResponseBody, APIError> converter = RestClient.retrofit().responseBodyConverter(APIError.class, new Annotation[0]);

        APIError error;

        try {
            error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new APIError();
        }

        return error;
    }
}
```

Custom Error class

```
 public class APIError {
        private int statusCode;
        private String message;

        public APIError() {
        }

        public int status() {
            return statusCode;
        }

        public String message() {
            return message;
        }
    }
```

My rest restAdapter

```
  restAdapter = new Retrofit .Builder()
                .baseUrl(ROOT)
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(LoganSquareConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

when i try to print error.message() its showing Could not locate ResponseBody converter.its working fine with Gson.let me know need to add anything extra while using LoganSquare

```
                APIError error = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
                Log.d("error message", error.message());
```